# How to add class to a html file loaded via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've included my header & footer at separate html files using `.load()` from jQuery. My jQuery code is below:

```
$(function(){
   $("#header").load("page-component/header.html"); 
   $("#footer").load("page-component/footer.html"); 
});
```

Right now, as I navigate to another page, I want to add an `active` class to one of my header/footer links but I can't seem to achieve that. Anyone can help me?

I've tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#menu-about').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `complete callback` of [**`jQuery.load`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

> `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )`

When you are invoking `addClass` method for element, `element` does not exist in `DOM`, `callback` function is invoked when `external` file is `loaded` in specified `element`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#header").load("page-component/header.html", function() {
    jQuery('#menu-about').addClass('active');
  });
  $("#footer").load("page-component/footer.html", function() {
    jQuery('#menu-about').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: @JoshuaRajandiran — I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_